# angular 5 problems with innerHtml + curly braces

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml

I am trying to use an HTML template with curly braces in a controller.

The problem I find is that when I use the innerHTML with safePipe, I see the curly braces and not the result.

**home.html** (template)

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of events">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**sanitizing.ts**

```
@Pipe({name: 'safe'})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
  switch (type) {
    case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
    case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
    case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
    case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
    case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
    default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
   }
 }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div [innerHtml]="myTemplate | safe: 'html'"></div>
```

**result**

```
{{item.name}}
```

**desired result**

```
dummy
```

Comment: what does `myTemplate` contain

Comment: the content of home.html, I get it with `return this._http.get ('./ assets / tpl / home.html')`

Comment: @GabrielSule you can't do that in the same way that you did in angular 1.x with `ng-include` directive.

Comment: @Serginho apart from the answer you gave me, is there any way to insert a template and curly braces return data?

Comment: No, the compiler works diferent, thunk about it. Where the template reads the variable to expand? There is no class component associated.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` doesn't compile angular templates.

If you want to insert a component dinamically, see [angular docs dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

```
 loadComponent() {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Type.component);


    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
```